# Second Controller not receiving data

Tags: swift, segue

I have two controllers and I am trying to pass data from the first one to second, but it is not receiving at all. I tried passing data as Properties and also using prepareForSegue, but some how, second view controller is not receiving the value from the first controller. First Controller is called **MainViewController** and second one is **FactViewController**. I am using this extension bellow because I am using a contentView inside my first screen. When I tap a cell from the content view I want to perform the data transference. `factValue` constant is receiving normally the data I want, but when I transfer it to the second controller (**FactViewController**) it doesn't transfer.

**USING PROPERTY WAY:**

```
extension MainViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let factValue = facts!.result[indexPath.row].value
        let fvc = FactViewController()

        fvc.receivedValue = factValue

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueMainscAndFactsc", sender: nil)
}
```

USING PREPAREFORSEGUE WAY:

```
extension MainViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let factValue = facts!.result[indexPath.row].value
        
        func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
            
            let destinationVC = segue.destination as! FactViewController
            destinationVC.receivedValue = factValue
        }
    }
}
```

This is my second viewController (FactViewController):

```
class FactViewController: UIViewController {

    var receivedValue: String = ""
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(receivedValue)
    }  
}
```

When I print the variable `receivedValue` in the second Controller inside `viewDidLoad` it still prints an empty `String`. Does any one has a suggestion to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first way is very obviously invalid. You say `let fvc = FactViewController()` and set its `receivedValue`, but then you throw it away and instead you trigger a segue which involves a *completely different* FactViewController. So the one you set the `receivedValue` is not the one whose view got loaded.

The second way is also invalid because your `prepareForSegue` is buried inside another a function (and has the wrong signature), so it never even gets called.

What you actually want is more like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueMainscAndFactsc", sender: nil)
}

func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)  {
    let destinationVC = segue.destination as! FactViewController
    let factValue = // ???
    destinationVC.receivedValue = factValue
}
```

Note that I've corrected your `prepare` signature.

The hard part here is working out what `factValue` should be. But for now, just make it some arbitrary value to convince yourself that this works! Then you can work on obtaining the correct value to hand over to the destination vc.

Comment: For the first one, if you are talking about `segueMainscAndFactsc`it is the name of the segue there in the StoryBoard. And about the second one, both ways I tried were inside of `didSelectItemAt` because it is the native method to do something when you tap the `collectionViewCell`,

Comment: if `prepareForSegue` is outside `didSelectItemAt`, where should I put `prepareForSegue`?

Comment: Anywhere you like. But your signature is wrong. It should be `func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`

Comment: I recommend that you stop and learn to use the debugger. It would have helped you a _lot_ on this because you would have seen for yourself what gets called with what values. There isn't much that's great about Xcode but the debugger is pretty darned good.

Comment: thanks for the tips, I am trying to figure out now how can I possible get the `indexPath` value from that extensions to use on the `prepareForSegue`

Comment: Does this help? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1615000-indexpathforselectedrow

Comment: Trying to inset it on my `extension MainViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource` but Xcode doesn't recognize that as function or method. I am trying to dissect that apple documentation you gave me